# Cannot intercept request in burp suite. I am having browser and burp settings done

Tags: security, burp

[Burp Proxy Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LYxl.png)

Although I on refreshing the site in a browser it captured in burp but the requests are not getting intercepted.

Browser setting- Manual proxy- 127.0.0.1, Port-8080
Burp Setting- Default- 127.0.0.1/8080

Answer (score 0):

@mrjay, with such a small amount of information, it's hard to tell what's going wrong. Can you provide a screenshot of your proxy configuration and the URL of the site that you're trying to intercept?

Secondly, have you adjusted your browser's proxy configuration, so that it routes requests through Burp Suite's proxy? If it helps, have a read through of [an introductory Burp Suite tutorial](https://matthewsetter.com/introduction-to-burp-suite/) that I wrote. It may help you out.

Comment: :I am trying to login www.flipkart.com
I have attached a screenshot link above in the description. Please have a look.

Comment: You only have the default intercept request rule active. That's going to match everything that isn't an image, CSS, or JavaScript file. So, if your browser's using a proxy, then it'll capture every request - which would be overwhelming. You'd know it was working. Pls upload a screenshot of your browser's proxy settings screen.